# Measure area in 3D models in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We need a function to measure areas in 3D models. Before we start coding our own tool from scratch I’m trying to se if there is a faster way to achieve this.

In 2D models it's possible to measure areas. Is there a simple way to enable this function in 3D models as well?

I’m aware that the calculations of the areas would be different in 3D and being able to override the calculations would be necessary.

Comment: I am checking with our Engineering to see if they could enlighten us on the best approach here stay tuned

Comment: Hi Bryan! Did you fint out anything?